# how to generate a print ready format with dynamic contents?

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt

Hello we have a non profit application built in Google App Engine for Java. 
This application allows people to register as Blood Donors on our system.

As a result we want to email them their print ready e-BloodDonor cards.

What is the way to create such cards where we can define the design of the card and contents are filled dynamically based on registered data?

Please advise

Comment: This question is too general, what exactly are you asking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create the layout in HTML, just like a normal view in your app, and then email them the link to that page to print it out. You could also go the much-more-complex route of generating PDFs or images for each user. [PDFBox](http://pdfbox.apache.org/) by Apache is pretty good for PDF generation.

I'd really recommend the HTML route, though, if it works for you. In my experience, it's much easier to do HTML layouts than it is to program PDF layouts in Java.

Comment: yeah we did something similar earlier and stored on google drive using app engine apis for it. but the conversion api's doesnt work to convert it to an image etc which we wanted to email to the blood donor rather sending the link. any advise?

Comment: dont remember now. it just returns null on trying to convert a text/html to image.